VSCode - "Debug Stop" turns off MACs applications
Me and my collegue are facing a very weird problem.
We are using Mac M2 with Arm chipset.
And whenever we stop debbuging a docker container, for example:

cmd+shift+p -> Debug: Start Debugging
cmd+shift+p -> Debug: Stop (other mac applications crashes, like Chrome, Slack, Docker, Calendar, Notes, almost everything. And then we are forced to turn the on again.)

I could not find anything related to this problem. I tried to delete extensions, remove all personalized short keybindings, and still it does not help.
How can this be possible at all ?
